# Are round check boxes confusing or an accepted standard?

Tags: checkboxes, standards, radio-buttons

I was browsing [dribbble.com](http://dribbble.com) today and came across a new [post](http://dribbble.com/shots/287612-Ongo-Modal-Styling) by one of the designers that I follow. He had posted a new modal form which was using rounded check boxes. I have never seen these before.

[image]

Are this an accepted standard, or are they confusing to the user (before they check them especially) because they look like radio buttons?

Update: Just found [another place](http://www.resco.net/developer/mobileformstoolkit/details.aspx?p=WindowsMobile&comp=TouchCheckBox) that uses them as well.

Update #2: After reading some of the comments, I realized this is present in iOS also, but I have never noticed. Also after going back Morgan's other work, I saw that his original design of this type of check box was a redesign of the current iOS one:

[image]

My guess as to where this came from is as a modification of the usual iOS delete button which is round. Since the only time the round check box shows up is when deleting messages, it must have been a clearer way to display that several messages were ready to be deleted, but they didn't give any thought to the fact that is looked like a radio button. It also seems to **only** be used when removing an item.

[image]

Comment: They really look like radio buttons, users would learn after they checked more than one of course, but will they try and check more than one...

Comment: I won't bother too much for this kind of stuff

Comment: @jimp and others allude to this, but you would think the term "check **boxes**" would have *insulated them against this kind of change in the first place*!

Comment: Microsoft is deliberately using circular (round) check boxes in their web applications. It breaks my philosophy the mutually exclusive radio button to the multi-select check boxes.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

If I saw that in an interface - I would assume only one item can be checked, especially before any had been selected. Only the wording of the title would indicate to me that multiple selection is possible. I think this design would lead to a greater than normal number of people choosing a single item rather than a selection of items.

I don't see the benefit here in bucking accepted trends other than to make it all curvy everywhere, but pretty rounded rectangles would do the job just as well, be more intuitive and more standard.

I don't dislike the appearance from a pure *graphical* perspective - I just don't think it's right from the *affordance* perspective.

-- edit update --

I redesigned it with rounded squares:

[image]

-- further update --

As an interesting addendum - I found this (below) on a Google spreadsheets viewform survey (from UXPin) recently. It combines the outer shape of a checkbox, so that multiple-answer questions and single-answer questions have options that look quite similar in appearance, but the single-answer options have the inner circular shape of a radio button.

I had no confusion as to how it might be used, but I found this representation very unusual - in fact this was the first time I'd seen it. I find this quite interesting.

[image]

Comment: That was my thought, but was curious what the overall sentiment was. I googled "round check box" and found a lot of hits regarding them, but until now have never seen one in use.

Comment: I doubt there's any research and I don't see any comments about their use so I didn't answer, but it's certainly no accepted standard.

Comment: It also reminds me of radio buttons, which only allow one selection.

Comment: "Only the wording of the title would indicate to me that..." - and we all know that no one reads dialog instructions or titles!

Comment: Maybe that's their (evil) plan - to subtly nudge the average number of selections towards 1, rather than encouraging the customer to select more than they would know what to do with (oh, the number of PDF files I've downloaded to "read someday")

Comment: Agree with @Roger. There is no change in the underlying behavior which is that of a check box, so tinkering with the conventional visual representation makes the user 'pause', creating an unintentional hindrance.

Comment: I am with @Roger on this one. Doing everything curvy is not the problem. In fact, OSX had rounded checkboxes for years and yet, they are clearly identified as such. Rounding the corners a bit would have been enough and would look like its wrapper box (ergo: nice from a design perspective). On a more negative note, the iOS is guilty of the same thing. Try selecting multiple SMS or Email, you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 43):

A check**box** should look like a box and not a circle. They are not check circles, after all. Subtly rounded corners, as others have mentioned, would be okay, but user interfaces have always represented a checkbox as a square and a radio button as a circle. The designers behind your examples are likely trying to be different, favoring style over function.

Comment: A simple yet very clear explanation! Good point!

Comment: I would disagree with your definition of "function." I would suggest you consider it a favor of style over _familiarity_. In essence, both buttons do exactly the same function.

Comment: And radio buttons should only be used on radios? :)

Comment: "but user interfaces have always represented a checkbox as a square and a radio button as a circle" That is simply not true. Checkboxes often used to be represented by diamond-shaped objects in the past.

Answer (score 28):

**A checkbox should be square.** As Cooper, Reimann, and Cronin wrote in [About Face 3](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470084111) (emphasis mine):

> Traditionally, checkboxes are square. Users recognize visual objects
>   by their shape, and the square checkbox is an important standard.
>   There is nothing inherently good or bad about squareness; it just
>   happens to have been the shape originally chosen and many users have
>   already learned to recognize this shape. There is no good reason to
>   deviate from this pattern. **Don't make them diamond shaped or round,
>   regardless of what the marketing or graphic arts people say.**

The round "checkboxes" in your second update seem to be a violation of [Apple's own Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/).

> People expect standard views and controls to look and behave
>   consistently across applications.
>
> **Follow the recommended usages for standard user interface elements.** In this way, users can depend on their prior experience to
>   help them as they learn to use your application.
>
> ...
>
> **Avoid radically changing the appearance of a control that performs a standard action.** If you use unfamiliar controls to perform standard
>   actions, users will spend time discovering how to use them and will
>   wonder what, if anything, your controls do that the standard ones do
>   not.

Notably, there's no mention of checkboxes or radio buttons in that document.

The [Mac OS X guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Controls/Controls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000359-TP6) describe how radio buttons and checkboxes should be used ("Use radio buttons, instead of checkboxes, to provide a set of choices from which users can choose only one."), and the standard checkbox control is a square with rounded corners.

Comment: +1 Great in depth answer. I added more to my question as to how they made that mistake going against their own rules.

Comment: Unfortunately, sice this (very fine) answer was posted almost half a decade ago, Apple has moved this document: [Apple's own Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/).

Comment: Half a decade? Wow! Thanks, the link has been updated.

Answer (score 9):

The round "boxes" implies that it's a different graphical representation of a radio button. A confusing one.

Whether or not that is the case, I do not know without reading the context. Rounded boxes is one thing, but circles are not as helpful as they could be as they use the visual language of a different widget that is close enough in functionality to cause cognitive dissonance.

Answer (score 6):

There's not quite enough context on the dribble.com posting to be certain if this will work. In the context of an app, these rounded checkboxes might work okay. They also might work if one of them is (always) checked by default (i.e. the checkmark image will help with understanding of the function).

However, there is no doubt in my mind that round checkboxes are NOT a standard; these look nice, but will cause confusion. [Jakob's Law of the Web User Experience](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/9605.html) says "users spend most of their time on other websites."

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the ios version is confusing.  What stops it from being seen as a radio button in the standard sense of the familiar circle with the dot in it as provided for many years by both the Windows and Mac OS, is the use of the tick iconography.  The tick suggests a tick box similar to a check (cross) box.  Not the surrounding border shape.  If they had used a round dot in a square box, then I believe that this would be confusing.  But why?  Ticks have been used as a replacement for a cross (or check) for years.  Look at the complete box on a to-do list.  No-one is confused by this.  So from my perspective, if the right iconography is used in design, then it does not matter what the surrounding border shape is.  Push the boat out. You could stars.  Not that I would.  :)

Answer (score -4):

I am in no way a UX expert, but I think they are fine depending.

If you're creating an application where useability is a top priority (Many Demographics), then you probably should avoid them...

But any website that targets youth. (ie twitter), then I think it makes no different. Any users in that demographic will figure it in like 2 seconds.

Comment: Usability should always be top priority

Comment: Agree to disagree. Functionality is always more important than usability.

Answer (score -4):

I am not convinced that most users know the different shapes for standard UI controls,  also I believe the iPhone UI may not keep to what most of us assume are the standards anyway.

So it all comes down to testing with the target users.   I expect that the wording on the site will have more effect on most users then the shape of any given control.

Comment: I agree: some users know the conventions and others don't, and similarly some users, when faced with uncertainty, will experiment, while others won't.  Take an educated guess, test it, and be prepared to make changes if you are wrong.

Comment: If we deviate from the convention, it's no longer a convention, so it's not helpful to anyone.